# How to remove the collateral tab when it is empty?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, magento-community

I created multi-select attribute to display the accessories in `product collateral tab` in details page. I added the accessories block like below:

```
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="catalog.product.accessories" template="catalog/product/accessories.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Accessories</value></action>
            </block>
```

Content in the `accessories.phtml` file to display the image of the `accessories` selected is below:

```
    <?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div class="feature"> 
    <span>
        <?php
             $Feature = explode(",",$_product->getResource()
             ->getAttribute('standard_accessories')->getFrontend()
             ->getValue($_product));
             foreach($Feature as $key => $value): ?>
             <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().$value ?>" ?>
                <?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."wysiwyg/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
             </a>     
        <?php /*echo $value; */?>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

Now when no accessories are selected for particular product the accessories tab should not be displayed.but it is displayed with broken image like below:

[image]

Someone kindly help me with this issue like Where and how should the condition be given to hide the tab when it is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create Accessories.php in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Accessories extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected $_product = null;

    function getProduct()
    {
        if (!$this->_product) {
            $this->_product = Mage::registry('product');
        }
        return $this->_product;
    }
}
```

and then add xml in your theme catalog.xml

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_accessories" name="product.accessories" as="accessories" template="catalog/product/view/accessories.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Accessories</value></action>
</block>
```

and add create accessories.phtml in your theme template in path catalog/product/view and put code

```
<?php $_accessories = $this->getProduct()->getAccessories(); ?>
<?php if ($_accessories): ?>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_accessories, 'accessories') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and this will tab only display if accessories has content.

here is updated code for your accessories.phtml

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $Feature = explode(",",$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('standard_accessories')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)); ?>
<?php if(count(array_filter($Feature, 'strlen')) > 0): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div class="feature"> 
    <span>
        <?php               
             foreach($Feature as $key => $value): ?>
             <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().$value ?>" ?>
                <?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."wysiwyg/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
             </a>     
        <?php /*echo $value; */?>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
    </span>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I followed your code.But  nothing is displayed inspite of value selected.

Comment: are u added all files ? becuase i test this in my local pc. and your code in accessories.phtml that's worked ?

Comment: as my accessories.phtml is for textarea attribute so please use your code in catalog/product/view/accessories.phtml

Comment: Yea I used your php and my phtml. Now when the accessories tab is getting displayed with broken image even when  value is not selected.

Comment: if there is not any thing selected then nothing need to genrated then only tab will not display so please take count of features array and if 0 then no need to display any thing.

Comment: Kindly help how to do it with my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43557/discussion-between-prashant-barot-and-ramya).

Comment: please check updated code

Comment: change code as i added ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43558/discussion-between-prashant-barot-and-ramya).

Comment: @Ramya i edit your file code copy and paste that will work perfect

Answer (score 0):

This is of course very confusing for customers,
so the better option would be to hide attribute value’s that are empty.
This can be done with a small piece of code. Find and open the attributes.phtml file. This file can be found here:

`/app/design/front end/[theme name]/[package name]/template/catalog/product/view/attribute.phtml`

Open the file and search for the following lines:

```
    
        htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>
        productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
```

Replace the entire foreach loop with the following lines of code:

```
    getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
    
        htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>
        productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
    
    



    getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
    
        htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>
        productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
```

Comment: should I give it within the for loop or should I replace the for loop?. Because I replaced for loop and am getting error like `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)`